# How to bind F-keys to shortcuts in 14.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 14.04

After upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04 Keyboard shortcuts using F-keys no longer function to activate keyboard functions.

For example, f16 binded to Home folder no longer works.  Nor does alt-F16

[1]: http://s18.postimg.org/6x1ei2ys9/1fkey.png keyboards

However when when Alt-F is binded to home folder keyboard shortcut works fine.

This is a new issue as I have had keys binded on many older versions of Ubuntu without issues.  Please let me know how to fix